# How to pass value from one component to another component

Tags: wcm

I am working with IBM WCM v8 and came with problem where I have to pass the value from one Menu Component **(Main Component)** to another Menu Component **(Inner Component)**.

Inner Component is called within Main Component. And I am using Main Component in `presentation template`.

I have tried using, setting `Application Level Session variable` using `Plugin component`, but somehow it won't work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to pass the value from one component to another component using Application Level Session variable available in plugin component. After setting the `compute="always"` in inner component, it works fine.